# Возможно ли добавить свое состояние в AsyncNotifier

Tags: flutter

Возможно ли добавить свое состояние в AsyncNotifier? Я знаю что в StateNotifier было возможно добавить в freezed класс, и затем добавить соответствующую функцию в метод when.
Но я попробовал использовать AsyncNotifier и у меня в виджете нет доступных своих функций таких как :initial,loading, loaded, error,loggedOut. Лишь доступны стандартные: data, error и loading

```
@freezed
abstract class UserState with _$UserState {
  const factory UserState.initial() = Initial;
  const factory UserState.loading() = Loading;
  const factory UserState.loaded(User user) = UserData;
  const factory UserState.error({String message}) = Error;
  const factory UserState.loggedOut() = LoggedOut; // новое состояние
}
```

---

Использование в виджете

```
final state = watch(userProvider);

return state.when(
  initial: () => InitialWidget(),
  loading: () => LoadingWidget(),
  loaded: (user) => UserWidget(user: user),
  error: (message) => ErrorWidget(message: message),
  loggedOut: () => LoggedOutWidget(), // обработка нового состояния
);
```